# Massive problem with unusable computer need help immediately

Tags: gnome, login, xfce

Ubuntu 18.04

I was trying to go from a gnome flashback session to an xfce one to see if it might be better to run a resource intensive game. I logged out and logged into the xfce and all that has happened is a grey screen with a movable cursor, but nothing else.

I cannot logout. I cannot start the xfce from ctrl-alt-f3 tty3 session. I cannot get into a tty 1 session. I have followed several ideas on this site and a couple of others to no avail.

I can get into a basic gnome session with startx, but as soon as I try to do anything via terminal, I get the message that things like -pkill are not installed (one of the things I was trying), and I cannot install anything. When I logout from that 800x600 session, it goes right back to the tty3 screen.

How do I get into the login screen so I can choose another known working desktop? I really need help ASAP.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you restarted the Display Manager?

i.e., sudo systemctl restart lightdm

or sudo systemctl restart gdm

Comment: I was (somehow) able to get the xfce desktop to show, albeit quite broken. I think I had no network, which is why I could not install things. As for the pkill situation, once I was able to logout and log back into a gnome session properly, pkill is there along with everything else.

Must have been some weird glitch in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get back to the xfce desktop after reinstalling the kernel headers. I know I did not touch anything like that, so weird. After the reinstall, I simply logged out of the tty session and got to the desktop. Not everything was working, but I was able to logout and get to the gdm screen. Logged into a known working gnome desktop and everything seems fine.

I would suggest that when using autoremove via terminal, pay close attention to what is being removed. I *think* this might be what happened.

Comment: Sometimes when installing different desktops, they do not play nice together.  Should try using a VM or even installing a separate dual boot to play around with installing extra desktops.

Comment: In your question, you never mentioned autoremove.

Comment: The autoremove is a repeat of the message that occurs when you `apt install|remove` packages (with install it's because they are listed as being removed because of clashes with newer packages).  This first warning is what you should taken notice of; the `autoremove` step was the last second chance. You shouldn't use add `apt -y install` unless you are sure about what's going to occur....  That "y" answer to the remove was your authorization to remove the packages...

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I did not mention it in my OP because I only thought about it after I got things back to normal.

Comment: @guiverc - you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @crip659 - good idea. Although I have never had an issue with switching desktops in the dozen or so years I've been using Linux. But a VM is something to think about.